# Using predict in metafor when each author has multiple rows in the data

Tags: r, nested, random-effects, metafor, multilevel-analysis

I'm running a meta-analysis where I'm interested in the effect of X on the effect of age on habitat use (raw mean values and variances) using the metafor package.

An example of one of my models is:

```
mod6 <-
  rma.mv(
    yi = Used_value,
    V = Used_variance,
    slab = Citation,
    mods = ~ Age + poly(Slope, degrees = 2),
    random = ~ 1 | Region,
    data = vel.focal,
    method = "ML"
  )
```

My justification for not using Citation as a random effect is that using only Region accounts for more of the heterogeneity than when `random = list( ~ 1 | Citation/ID, ~ 1 | Region)` or when Citation/ID is used by itself.

What I need for output is the prediction for each age by region, but the predict() function for the model and the associated forest plot spits out the prediction for each row, as it assumes each row in the data is a unique study. In my case it is not as I have my input values separated by age and season.

```
predict(mod6)

                                  pred     se   ci.lb   ci.ub   pi.lb   pi.ub 
Riehle and Griffith 1993.1        9.3437 2.3588  4.7205 13.9668  0.2362 18.4511 
Riehle and Griffith 1993.2        9.3437 2.3588  4.7205 13.9668  0.2362 18.4511 
Riehle and Griffith 1993.3        9.3437 2.3588  4.7205 13.9668  0.2362 18.4511 
Spina 2000.1                      8.7706 2.7386  3.4030 14.1382 -0.7364 18.2776 
Spina 2000.2                      8.5407 2.7339  3.1824 13.8991 -0.9611 18.0426 
Spina 2000.3                      8.5584 2.7406  3.1868 13.9299 -0.9509 18.0676 
Vondracek and Longanecker 1993.1 12.6116 2.5138  7.6847 17.5385  3.3462 21.8769 
Vondracek and Longanecker 1993.2 12.6116 2.5138  7.6847 17.5385  3.3462 21.8769 
Vondracek and Longanecker 1993.3 12.3817 2.5327  7.4176 17.3458  3.0965 21.6669 
Vondracek and Longanecker 1993.4 12.3817 2.5327  7.4176 17.3458  3.0965 21.6669
```

Does anybody know a way to modify the arguments inside predict() to tell it how you want your predictions output or to tell it that there are multiple rows per slab?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `newmods` argument to specify the values for `Age` for which you want predicted values. You will have to plug in something for the linear and quadratic terms for the `Slope` variable as well (e.g., holding `Slope` constant at its mean and hence the quadratic term will just be the mean squared). `Region` is not a fixed effect, so it is not relevant if you want to compute predicted values based on the fixed effects. If you want to compute BLUPs for those random effects, you can do so with `ranef()`. One can then combine the predictions based on the fixed effects with the BLUPs. That would be the general idea, but implementing this will require a bit of programming.